# Hook to function without delegates (Reflection)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

Is there a way I could use reflection to hook one function to another without using delegates?

```
class A
{
    void Foo()
    {
    }
}

class B
{
    void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.GetType().GetMethod("Foo").AddHook(a, Func); //I want something like this
        a.Foo();
        //Func gets called
    }

    void Func()
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a way to call `Func` after `Foo` was called without using events, delegates or just calling `Func` from inside `Foo`?

I need this so my game's UI controller can get updated.

The way I see most people dealing with this is by adding a bunch of events to A and subscribing B to those. Like this

```
class A
{
‎    public delegate void UICallback();
‎    public event UICallback onFoo;
    void Foo()
    {
    ‎    onFoo.Invoke();
    }
}

class B
{
    void Main()
    {
        A a = new A();
        ‎a.onFoo += Func;
        a.Foo();
    }

    void Func()
    {
    }
}
```

The problem I find with this approach is that I'd need to add a bunch of events like these (probably more than 5 or even 10) to many classes and then remember to invoke those at the end of a function to update UI (invoke onBattleStarted at the end of StartBattle(), for example). This, in addition to increasing the size of my classes with big blocks of event declarations making it ugly to read, makes it a harder maintain.

**EDIT** I think no one really understands what I'm looking for... I'd like a way to hook `Func` to `Foo` without making any changes to `Foo`, i.e. without `Foo` knowing this callback exists. Using an action won't help since I'd need specify on `Foo`'s parameters that it should call `Func`

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's really unclear what the scope is here. Yes, you can call `a.Foo(); b.Func();` - what's wrong with that? I assume that *wouldn't* suffice, but you really haven't explained why.

Comment: Like I said, I want this so my UI controller knows what has happened. I could call `Func` from inside `Foo`, but this situation will happen in many places and I think it would be much more organized to just hook one function to another on one place (which would be the Init function of my UI controller).

Comment: [Interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface).

Comment: Sorry, that's still *really* unclear to me. I'm sure you may have a clear idea of what you mean, but it's not at all clear to me - which suggests it may well not be clear to other readers either.

Comment: I edited the question, take a look at the code.

Comment: You could *probably* do it with something like [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody), but I think it is a really bad idea in general. As a general warning, even *trying* to use Fody for this will be EXTREMELY COMPLICATED.

Comment: Its a terrible idea. Reflection is usually much slower than using events and delegates. Events are the backbone of decoupled code. Get used to it.

Comment: So you want a bunch of references to a single instance of class `A` that you will call `a.Foo()` on? Or are you trying to get `a.Foo()` to execute some function in `B`?

Comment: Upvoting your question because you have clearly put effort into forming and revising the question. That said, like others here I fundamentally question this approach.  In general if the vast majority of developers do it a certain way, there's usually (ok not ALWAYS, but usually) a really good reason for that.    What might make your question stronger is if you included a more detailed example of the "normal" approach as it relates to the specific UI tasks you're trying to accomplish, and then point out what specifically you find undesirable about that approach and why (performance? clarity?)

Comment: You can add Action parameter call it onFinish to Func and when you call Func you call Foo.
Ex: void Func(Action onFinish)
and you call it like this Func( () => Foo())

Comment: Does the "hook" need to *only* apply to the specific `a` instance of `A`, or can it apply to *any* instance of `A`? For example, if I added `var a2 = new A(); a2.Foo();` to the end of your `Main` method, should `Func` be called?

Comment: In my case it doesn't really matter (I think) BUT it would be nice if I could add the hook to a specific instance.

Comment: I tried my solution and it worked as you ask with no changes to Foo function.

Answer (score 2):

You Can call Action at the end of Func().

```
Class A
{
   void Foo()
   {
   }
}

Class B
{
   void Main()
   {
    A a = new A();
    Func( () => {a.Foo();});
   }

   void Func(Action onFinish)
   {
    //Enter your code here
    onFinish();
   }
```

Comment: I think this is backwards.  OP wants to have calls to `A.Foo` automatically call `B.Func` when they complete.

Answer (score 0):

There is the **method chaining** pattern if that can solve your problem:

```
namespace Assets
{
    public class Example
    {
        public Example GrabSomeFoodInTheFridge()
        {
            // some work
            return this;
        }

        public Example WatchTv()
        {
            // some work
            return this;
        }

        public Example EatFood()
        {
            // some work
            return this;
        }
    }

    public class Demo
    {
        public Demo()
        {
            var example = new Example();

            var instance = example
                .GrabSomeFoodInTheFridge()
                .EatFood()
                .WatchTv();
        }
    }
}
```

It does not use reflection at all, additionally you could leverage interfaces and extension methods.